# Variable not incrementing in for loop

Tags: bash, variable, for

I am trying to print the number of directories in the working directory. For some reason my counter is not incrementing. Can you please tell me why?

```
#!/bin/bash
n=0
for afile in $(ls)
do
    if [ -d $afile ]
    then
      (( n ++ ))
    fi
done
echo There are $n directories under the current directory $(pwd).
exit 0
```

Oddly, this program seems to iterate through ls .. (up directory)

```
for myfile in $(ls ..)
do
    if [ -d "../$myfile" ]
    then
      echo "../$myfile (dir)"
    else
      echo ../$myfile
    fi
done
exit 0
```

Comment: Sorry, I think we edited at the same time. You might want to add back your changes.

Comment: Are you sure? I just refreshed and the code block looks OK now.

Comment: Oh okay, maybe we made the same change anyway!

Comment: So when you run this, is the output always 0 directories? It works for me, although you need to quote properly.

Comment: Yes, it's always 0. Can you explain what is wrong with my quotes?

Comment: I'll write an answer up.

Comment: No worries. Let me know if I haven't explained anything properly

Answer (score 1):

For counting the number of non-hidden directories (in the current directory), using `bash`:

```
shopt -s nullglob
set -- */
printf 'There are %d non-hidden subdirectories in %s\n' "$#" "$PWD"
```

To include the count of hidden directories:

```
shopt -s dotglob nullglob
set -- */
printf 'There are %d subdirectories in %s\n' "$#" "$PWD"
```

What these pieces of code do is to expand the pattern `*/` and to count the number of names that the pattern expands to. The pattern, since it ends with a slash, will *only* expand to directory names (or to names of symbolic links to directories).

The directory names will be assigned to the positional parameters, `$1`, `$2` etc. using `set`, and the number of these parameters is kept in `$#` by the shell (so there's no need to actually loop over them to count them).

If you feel more comfortable with `bash` arrays:

```
shopt -s dotglob nullglob
dirs=( */ )
printf 'There are %d subdirectories in %s\n' "${#dirs[@]}" "$PWD"
```

This is essentially the same thing, except it uses a named array instead of the positional parameters.

The `dotglob` shell option, in `bash`, will make `*` match hidden names as well as non-hidden names.  The `nullglob` shell option will make non-matching patterns expand to nothing.

Related:

- [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what do to instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985)
- [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803)
- [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766)

Comment: Your solution will print 1 in the case where there are no subdirectories. You may use the unportable `nullglob`; `shopt -s nullglob; set -- */ .[!.]/ .??*/`.

Comment: @UncleBilly Thanks. It should be enough with `nullglob` for `bash` though, and a test on `$1` in `/bin/sh` (which I'm not covering here). I will update ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me, but there are a few errors in it that will fail in some cases (e.g. if a filename has a space in it).

- Firstly, don't [parse ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Instead iterate using a glob. i.e. instead of `$(ls)`, use `*`.
- When reading variables, you should quote them, i.e. use `"$foo"` instead of `$foo`. If you do not quote them, the shell will split the output on the IFS (i.e. the spaces). You can test this with your script. Include some directories with no spaces, then test with a space. Only the former will be counted.

Here is the fixed code:

```
#!/bin/bash
n=0
for afile in *
do
    if [ -d "$afile" ]
    then
      (( n ++ ))
    fi
done
echo There are $n directories under the current directory $(pwd).
exit 0
```

I'm not sure if this is obvious, but the script will run in the current directory.

Comment: Thanks Sparhawk! That definitely works. But in my assignment I am required to use the ls command. Is there ANY reasonable way to parse and iterate through ls?

Comment: @Benjamin not really. This is an example: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/117549

Comment: I agree that there's no way to parse `ls` that works for all files. You might be able to use something like `find`, but that probably not allowed either. One hacky way to count directories with `ls` is to use `ls -F` (see `man ls`) and search for `/`.